# After changing branch I lost my code from it

Tags: git, branch

I know this is a bit newbie question. I have my frontend branch and backend branch. I wrote backend code on this one branch and when I switch tu frontend my code from backend is not visible. What sould I do, just merge them together?

Cheers

Comment: If you have committed the changes, just merge the backend branch into a common branch (eg master). Then merge master into your frontend branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to view the back end code again switch back to the back end branch. In  git, a branch has its own code the whole purpose of creating branches is to keep a separate copy for adding features or doing any change without affecting the master branch normally this is a

Comment: Ok, I got it. When I want to test my app I need to run Spring application to see data in my frontend part. So as Terry said above I need to merge them. Ok, thank you